# Xampp can't start apache in Windows 10

Tags: windows, apache, xampp

I updated to Windows 10 today and I need to install XAMPP. When I do, I have one problem. When I start Apache, it gives me the following error:

This is from the apache log:

```
[Sun Aug 16 20:31:11.735761 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 4600:tid 164] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Sun Aug 16 20:31:12.230789 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 4600:tid 164] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Sun Aug 16 20:31:13.463859 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4600:tid 164] AH00455: Apache/2.4.16 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1p PHP/5.6.11 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Aug 16 20:31:13.463859 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4600:tid 164] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC11 Server built: Jul 12 2015 10:56:48
[Sun Aug 16 20:31:13.463859 2015] [core:notice] [pid 4600:tid 164] AH00094: Command line: 'C:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache'
[Sun Aug 16 20:31:13.475859 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4600:tid 164] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 1920
[Sun Aug 16 20:31:15.265137 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 1920:tid 480] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Sun Aug 16 20:31:15.663212 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 1920:tid 480] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Sun Aug 16 20:31:15.863341 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1920:tid 480] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I guess windows10 still doesn't support a local host feature.

Comment: I found the solution, if you run the XAMPP Control Panel as administrator, works perfectly in Windows 10. Thanks for answering!

Comment: That could also be the problem. Good you found it.

Comment: Please don't add "Solved" to your title. You can post the answer on its own, and even accept it. That is the proper indication  for others with a similar question.